# Теряется фильтр feGaussianBlur при экспорт в fabricjs из SVG

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Здравствуйте.
Я экспортирую в fabricjs кнопку, созданную в illustratore, с помощью функции loadSVGFromString, но теряется фильтр feGaussianBlur. В чем может быть проблема?
Прикладываю код кнопки.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-161 353.2 288 86.8" enable-background="new -161 353.2 288 86.8">
 <defs>
  <filter id="0">
   <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4"/>
  </filter>
  <linearGradient id="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" y1="340.57" x2="0" y2="389.32">
   <stop stop-color="#fff"/>
   <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"/>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <g opacity=".35" filter="url(#0)">
  <path d="m107 430.2h-248c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-42.2c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h248c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v42.2c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12"/>
 </g>
 <path d="m115 425.2h-264c-6.6 0-12-5.4-12-12v-48c0-6.6 5.4-12 12-12h264c6.6 0 12 5.4 12 12v48c0 6.6-5.4 12-12 12" fill="#306296"/>
 <path d="m114.3 354.7h-261.4c-4 0-6.2.6-8.6 2.6-2.1 1.7-3.5 4.2-3.8 7.4v15c32.7 7.8 80.6 12.7 134.4 12.7 63.6 0 120.6-6.9 150.6-17.2v-10.6c0-2.8-1.5-5.1-3-6.6-2-2-4.1-3.3-8.2-3.3" fill="url(#1)"/>
</svg>
```